# Is it possible to keep the original hypothesis while using intro pattern

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a theorem that involves dependent pairs (sigT). It's goal looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
forall x : {x : G | P x}, mult1 sub_e x = x
```

When I run `intros [x Px].`, The following is added into the context:

```
x : G
Px : P x
```

Is it possible to keep the variable for the dependent pair as a whole? I have to run `set (x_pair := exist P x Px).` to put it into the context:

```
x : G
Px : P x
x_pair := exist P x Px : {x : G | P x}
```

Is it possible to do it without an extra command?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it: define a record that contains a duplicated information, use the `%` intro pattern to build a value of this record and then destruct it:

```
(* sing_copy contains a copy of the value sing_val *)
Record Sing A := sing { sing_val : A ; sing_copy := sing_val }.
Arguments sing {A} _.

Variable X : Type.
Variable P : X -> Prop.

Goal forall z : { x : X | P x }, bool.
Proof.
  intros [[x Hx] x_pair]%sing.
```

However this does not seem to work for goals depending on the value to be destructed. In that case here are 2-3 relatively straightforward and more robust ways to achieve the same thing

```
Definition dupl {A B} (f : forall (a : A), let x := a in B a) : forall a : A, B a := f.

Ltac add_let :=
  change (forall a : ?A, @?B a) with (forall a : A, let z := a in B a).

Variable X : Type.
Variable P : X -> Prop.

Goal { x : X | P x } ->  bool.
Proof.
  (* intro the term, duplicate it before destructing it *)
  intros z; pose (x_pair := z); destruct z as [x Hx].
  Restart.
  (* duplicate before using an intro pattern *)
  apply dupl; intros [x Hx] x_pair.
  Restart.
  (* same thing using change instead of the application of a lemma *)
  add_let ; intros [x Hx] x_pair.
```